# Is this memory compatible with this motherboard?

Tags: desktop, memory, pc

I would like to buy new memory for my PC desktop. My ASUS motherboard model is P8H61-M LE/BR. I've got the following information in the [ASUS site](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P8H61M_LEUSB3/specifications/):

> 2 x DIMM, Max. 16GB, DDR3 1333/1066 Hz Non-ECC, Un-buffered Memory
>
> Dual Channel Memory Architecture Supports Intel® Extreme Memory
>   Profile (XMP)
>
> The maximum 16GB memory capacity can be supported with 8GB or above DIMMs. ASUS will update the memory QVL once the DIMMs are available in
>   the market.

So I want to buy two 8GB RAM sticks in order to have 16GB in my PC. I've found these ones on the market:

- [Site 1](http://www.ebay.com/itm/8GB-Kingston-KVR1333D3N9-8G-DDR3-PC3-10600-1333MHz-CL9-240pin-Desktop-DIMM-/141992691627?hash=item210f6c87ab:g:fbwAAOSwYmZXNw~0)
- [Site 2](http://www.ebay.com/itm/QTY-1x-8GB-DDR3-PC3-10600U-1333Mhz-non-ECC-desktop-memory-PAREEMA-for-desktop-PC-/141823346926?hash=item21055488ee:g:n5MAAOSwhcJWQBBp)
- [Site 3](http://www.dx.com/p/kingston-valueram-8gb-1333mhz-ddr3-non-ecc-cl9-dimm-desktop-memory-kvr1333d3n9-8g-852319631#.VzgBS77eM1w)

So is this memory compatible with my PC? Are some of them better than others?

Answer (score 3):

As long as you have DDR3 Memory at the right speed you'll be fine, as this is what your motherboard specifies. All three of the RAM modules you listed would work perfectly fine.

Brand names don't *necessarily* matter, but I've tended to have better luck (and customer service) with well known brands.

You may want to keep an eye out for latency and clock speed if you're really gung-ho about getting the most speed. The CL or CAS latency numbers are what you look at here, but often the difference in latency is so small that there really is no discernible difference. The lower the latency, the better, in essence.

If I were you and I had a choice between those three, I'd choose either of the Kingston branded ones.